# Can I create a static library using ScalaNative on linux?

Tags: linux, scala-native

I've written some code I'd like to share across a couple of ScalaNative command line tools I'm working on.

Can I generate a library (preferably static) that I can share between multiple ScalaNative console applications?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from Scala Native [0.4.8](https://scala-native.org/en/latest/changelog/0.4.8.html) it can generate dynamic and static libraries.

What you need to do is add the following to your `build.sbt` file.

To generate a dynamic library:

```scala
import scala.scalanative.build.BuildTarget

nativeConfig ~= {
  _.withBuildTarget(BuildTarget.libraryDynamic)
}
```

To generate a static library:

```scala
import scala.scalanative.build.BuildTarget

nativeConfig ~= {
  _.withBuildTarget(BuildTarget.libraryStatic)
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).